# Wordpress Image source shows src="blob:https

Tags: wordpress

My WordPress post image source shows src="blob:https/mydomain/641016c7-831a-4bc6-9909-25b30c3bb07b" and the image is broken. I can't understand how it occurred and what does it mean? Could you please tell me what is it and how can I get back my original image?

Answer (score 0):

name picture 641016c7-831a-4bc6-9909-25b30c3bb07b .

find picture in dashboard -> media -> library
delet this picture and upload new picture in post.

Comment: There's no such image or file in the upload folder or in the media library.